# Comparing strings in php retrieved from sql server database issue

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server Database, where one of my table has a column type **VARCHAR(MAX)**. In this column I am storing the BASE64 string.

Basically the flow of the app is:

1. get the fingerprint data.
2. encode it into BASE64 String.
3. Store it to the sql server database using PHP by checking its existence

   3a. Retrieve all the fingerprints from the database

   3b. check the to be inserted fingerprint data with all fingerprints received from the database

   3c. if any fingerprint matches with it , then return false
       if any fingerprint does not match with it, return true
4. if return value is true , then insert the fingerprint with following query , if false then show error.

   ```
   INSERT INTO EMPTABLE ( Finger_Data ) values (  CONVERT( VARCHAR(MAX) , 
   $Finger_Data ) )
   ```

To get and check the fingerprints at step no 3, the following code is used.

```
 $sqlString = "SELECT  CAST( Finger_Data AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS FINGER FROM 
 EMPTABLE ";

 $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sqlString);
            $stmt->execute();
            $data = $stmt->fetchAll();

  if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {

     if ($data) {
         foreach ($data as $row) {

                        $found = false;

                        if ($Finger_Data === $row['FINGER']){

                            echo "\n >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 
                            Duplicate found <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< \
                            $found = true;

                        }

                        if($found){
                            echo "\n >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 
                            Implementing found <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< \
                        }

         }

    }

  }
```

Here my question is, I am not be able to compare these two strings at all.
When I print those two variables, I see them 80 percent equals while other 
part of the string is not matching. However when I directly check in database 
the data shows correctly, that means reading in PHP or writing from matters.

Comment: Q: You're not expecting the fingerprint stored in the database to be *IDENTICAL* to a fingerprint the same employee enters later, are you?  You need to 1) Read the fingerprint from the reader, 2) read the stored fingerprint from MSSQL, 3) Use a 3rd party library to compare them to determine if there's a "match".

Comment: No, its not the case. I am checking with all the fingerprints with the current given fingerprint. If it matches with any of then dont insert but if does not matches insert. Also no 3rd party library i am using to compare them.

Comment: Again - you're not expecting two fingerprints taken by the same person with the same reader to be "identical", are you?  They *won't* be.  So exactly how are you comparing fingerprints, if not with a 3rd party library?

Answer (score 0):

You can not do the comparison in SQL as , only if you have the same fingerprint image again and again, you would get it matched. But in the reality, When you get the fingerprint two times, both the images will be different from each other with little bit position change, angle change, and quality of the scan. So String comparison is not possible.

All the scanners do provide the SDK for capturing the fingerprint and comparing them (1:1) which you can use for developing the desktop application. If you need to compare the scanned images at the server, then you need to implement your own Automatic Finger Identification algorithm or you have to use third party services such as

1. [CAMS](http://camsunit.com/application/javascript-based-fingerprint-scanner-for-website-authentication-and-attendance.html#compare-fingerprint)
2. [M2Sys](http://www.m2sys.com)
3. [Neurotechnology](https://www.neurotechnology)